# How do I make the last letter blink?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code I use for my self-typing text, I want the last letter to blink, how do I achieve that here?

I tried using a timer to make the letter blink, but it isn't a very good solution for what I'm trying to do.

This is what it looks like: https://gyazo.com/97a4ef9866fb9d925da1f47ff0b9b21f, I want to achieve a cmd-like effect.

```
<div style="color:#c0c0c0;font-size:72px;font-family:Windows Command Prompt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;" id="text_scroller"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var messages = new Array
(
   'Click here to begin_'
);
var speed = 150;
var currentMsg = 0;
function doScroller(text, pos, direction)
{
   var text_scroller = document.getElementById('text_scroller');
   text_scroller.innerText = '//' + text.substring(0, pos) + '';

   pos += direction;
      if (pos > text.length)
   {
      text = ' '
   }
      else
   {
     if (pos < 0)
     {
        currentMsg++;
        if(currentMsg >= messages.length)
          currentMsg = 0;
        text = messages[currentMsg];
        direction = -direction;
     }
     setTimeout('doScroller("'+text+'",'+pos+','+direction+')', speed);
   }
}
doScroller(messages[0], 0, 1);
</script>
```

Comment: you want the `underscore` to blink, or any character which is at last to blink ? like `o` in **Hello** or it should be **Hello_**

Comment: I want the underscore to blink.

Comment: check if  that's ok -  https://jsfiddle.net/6Lje2L9y/

Comment: If possible, I have to avoid using deprecated browser functions :D.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5tcrjL02/ This should work, but so does all the other solutions though. You shouldn't do it pure JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="color:#c0c0c0;font-size:72px;font-family:Windows Command Prompt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;" id="text_scroller"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var messages = new Array
(
   'Click here to begin_'
);
var speed = 150;
var currentMsg = 0;

function doScroller(text, pos, direction)

{
   var text_scroller = document.getElementById('text_scroller');
   text_scroller.innerText = '//' + text.substring(0, pos) + '';

   pos += direction;

   if (pos == 20)
   {
      direction = -direction;
   }

   if (pos == 19)
   {
      direction = 1;
      speed = 500;
   }



     setTimeout('doScroller("'+text+'",'+pos+','+direction+')', speed);
}
doScroller(messages[0], 0, 1);
</script>
```

This was what I wanted to do. I don't know enough javascript, so I have no clue if I wrote it logically, but it does work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `_` to blink, then this can be achieved by pure CSS.

```css
.blinker:after {
  content: '_';
  display: inline-block;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blinker">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in pure javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Using plain css:

```css
.writer:after {
  content: "_";
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    1% {opacity: 0;}
    50% {opacity: 0;}
    51% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<span class="writer">Test</span>
```

Note that this won't wor kin IE9 or lower, and requires the `webkit-` prefix in Safari 4.0 - 8.0.